# CSS Positioning anchor inside li vertically aligned

Tags: html, css, navigation, positioning, html-lists

I'm making a horizontal navigation menu, and i want to center vertically the anchors inside the divs using CSS, what i have is this:

```
<nav id="header-nav">
    <ul id="menu-header-menu" class="dropdown dropdown-horizontal">
        <li id="menu-item-24" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page">
            <a href="http://localhost/rototec.com.co/pagina-ejemplo/">
                Inicio
            </a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-23" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page">
            <a href="http://localhost/rototec.com.co/filosofia-y-politicas-de-calidad/">
                Filosofía y políticas de calidad</strong>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-22" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page">
            <a href="http://localhost/rototec.com.co/catalogo-de-productos/">
                Catálogo de productos
            </a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-21" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page">
            <a href="http://localhost/rototec.com.co/proceso-de-rotomoldeo/">
                Proceso de rotomoldeo
            </a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-20" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page">
            <a href="http://localhost/rototec.com.co/contacto/">
                Contacto
            </a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-19" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page">
            <a href="http://localhost/rototec.com.co/preguntas-frecuentes/">
                Preguntas frecuentes
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Right now all line heights (a, li and ul) are 15, my UL height is 45 and so is the li... the anchor height is not set, how can i make them center vertically?

This is my CSS:

```
ul.dropdown {
    font: bold 12px tt0142m, FuturaM, "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: block;
    height: 45px;
    padding: 0px;
    line-height: 15px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
/*  border: 1px solid green; */
}
ul.dropdown li {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
ul.dropdown a {
    text-decoration: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: #000;
}

ul.dropdown li {
    word-wrap: break-word;
    width: 120px;
    text-align: center;
    font: FuturaM;
    border-left: 2px solid #000;
    line-height: 15px;
    height: 45px;
}
ul.dropdown > li:last-child {
    border-right: 2px solid black;
}
ul.dropdown li a {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: #000;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

By the way, right now all the links are vertically aligned at the top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to change the display type to table and then force heights on the elements

```
ul.dropdown li {
display: table;
min-height: 45px;
}
ul.dropdown li a {
display: table-cell;
height: 45px;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

The problem with doing it like this is that IE7 and ie6 need some special styling

```
ul.dropdown li {
position: relative;
display: block;
}
ul.dropdown li a {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
display: block;
}
ul.dropdown li a <new extra element that you do not yet have> {
position: relative;
top: -50%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to make the `li`s `display: table-cell;`. Table elements are the only onces that can vertically align content in the middle at the moment (within reasonable support)

Here is [a jsfiddle that demonstrates this](http://jsfiddle.net/sg3s/PVhGe/1/). `display: table-cell` is not supported by IE7 but I don't think that is a problem for you, your using the psuedo selector `:last-child` which is not supported by IE7 either.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, and also thanks for the link, i didn't know about that site. Gonna try and do what you say. I think your answer is similar to Dennis, but he suggests making the li{ display: table; } while making the a{ display: table-cell; }

Comment: Ah, yeah thats a little more work but basically the same, making it a table element.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean that you want the anchors vertically aligned within the li's...

```
ul.dropdown li {
posiiton:relative;
}
ul.dropdown li a {
height:25px; /* change as needed */
position:absolute;
top:10px; /* change as needed */
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work, at least is not doing what i expect. My idea is to center vertically all the contents on the li. Some of those texts use 3 lines, some 2 lines and some 1 line. The idea is that all of them have the same space in the top and in the bottom (0 for 3 liners, 7 for 2 liners and 15 for 3 liners ... basically centered vertically)

Comment: Tables then. Or, you can try displaying the blocks as table cells.