# Vertically aligning text inside a link inside an <li> that needs to expand horizontally

Tags: html, css

I need to make a menu that on mobile has the links expand to full width. Something similar to this wireframe. 
[image: Intended]

My code so far:

**HTML**

```
<div id="shortcuts">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Categories</a></li>
        <li><a href="#archives">Archives</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 180px;
    background-color: #666;
    color: #fff;
}

#shortcuts { position: absolute; z-index: 20; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; }

#shortcuts ul {
    display: table;
    width:100%;

    height: 180px; /* for testing only */
}

#shortcuts ul li {
    list-style: none;   
    display: table;
    height: 60px;
    width:100%;
    display: block; 
    vertical-align: middle;

    background-color: red;   /* for testing only */
    border: blue 3px solid;  /* for testing only */
}

#shortcuts ul li a {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;       
    text-decoration: none;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;

    border: 2px dashed green; /* for testing only */
}
```

This is my result so far (colors used only for testing)

[image: current progress]

If I change the `#shortcuts ul li a` to `display: block;`, I can get the desired width. But then the text will not center vertically.

Not a duplicate of [CSS Positioning anchor inside li vertically aligned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9875204/css-positioning-anchor-inside-li-vertically-aligned) because that is only partial part to vertically align the text. Does not answer how to make the link expand 100% width.

Comment: You can't just use something like `padding:10px 0px;` ?

Comment: add `line-height:60px;` to the links, along with the `display: block;`

Comment: @JoshC I thought the same thing. And visually it does create the desired effect. But it made the links overlap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use both "`display: block;`" and "`line-height:60px;`" for "#shortcuts ul li a {"

Updated code:

```
#shortcuts ul li a {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;       
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block; 
    line-height:60px;
    vertical-align: middle;

    border: 2px dashed green; /* for testing only */
}
```

Please refer the fiddle :- **http://jsfiddle.net/aasthatuteja/6WEW6/**

Comment: Infact, you can remove the " height: 60px; " property from "#shortcuts ul li a", as after giving "line-height" this is not required, its doing the samething